# Only associate register 0 with system clipboard in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim

Currently I've `set clipboard+=unnamed`, which afaik links the unnamed VIM register with the system clipboard.

What I want though, is to only associate Vims register 0 with the system clipboard, which "will always contain the most recently yanked text, but never deleted text"[1].

This would make it so, that my systems clipboard (which has its own history) does not get *spammed* with contents of delete, change and put operations from Vim, e.g. that only yank operations from Vim are shared with the system clipboard.

Is this possible?

1) https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/advanced-vim-registers/

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't *exactly* what you describe, I wonder if you might like the behaviour of:

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

Details in `:help clipboard`. Essentially, this links the system clipboard provider to yank operations, so that when you yank text it's placed into the following registers (on my machine at least):

```
""
"0
"+
```

This avoids the necessity of <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> and friends. Deletion will populate:

```
""
"1
"+
```

because delete usually skips register 0 in any case. So this might approach what you're after?

I believe on some systems registers `*` and `+` are the same, so you may find it populates `*` on yours too. Pasting will be from `+` unless another register is specified.

**Option without `unnamedplus`**

Another approach would be to specifically bind your yank operations to the behaviour that works for you, using your leader key. I've seen this in a few `init.vim`'s, although I don't find this especially useful myself. For example:

```
nnoremap <leader>y "+y
vnoremap <leader>y "+y
nnoremap <leader>p "+p
vnoremap <leader>p "+p
```

Again, not quite what you asked for but I suspect beyond this you're looking at writing a plugin that responds to changes in registers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have clarified that I'm aware of the unnamedplus option. I added to my question what I want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: No worries. I can't think of a way to get the specific behaviour you describe, but I added another option to my answer.

Comment: Interesting approach though 

Answer (score 1):

Another half-solution is to use the autoselect mode of clipboard integration:

```
if has("clipboard")
  if v:version > 703 || v:version == 703 && has('patch597')
      set clipboard^=autoselectplus
  else
      set clipboard^=autoselect
  endif
endif
```

This will only sync yanks from visual-mode selections to your clipboard. 
If you have mouse mode enabled, you can click-to-select and `y` the region into the clipboard-synced `+` buffer. Or just use `v` to initiate a selection.

I realize that is not as keystroke efficient as simply masking the unnamed register from the clipboard integration, as you suggested, so that simple edit-mode yanks (`yy`) are also synced but `dd` & `x` will not. But `autoselect` will keep your clipboard cleaner.

Comment: Good idea, will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, it work for me on my Windows.

```
:nnoremap <expr> y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'y'
:nnoremap <expr> yy (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'yy'
:nnoremap <expr> Y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'Y'
:xnoremap <expr> y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'y'
:xnoremap <expr> Y (v:register ==# '"' ? '"+' : '') . 'Y'
```